# Getting a value after the object was created from user input Tkinter Python

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, instance-variables

I cannot figure this out even though I watched videos about Object Oriented Programming and Classes in python.

Simplified scenario: 2 classes.
class1 is basically a window with two buttons (button1 creates an object of 2nd class and button2 gets the value from inside of this newly created object Entry widget via entrybox.get())

class2 is a frame with tkinter Entry widget on it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class WindowClass:

    def create_frame(self):
        new_window = FrameClass(self.master)

    def get_value(self):
        """WHAT CODE DO I PUT HERE TO GET THE VALUE ENTERED BY USER INTO THE ENTRYBOX?"""
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        root = tk.Tk()
        self.master = root
        self.master.geometry('500x500')

        self.create_frame_button = tk.Button(self.master,
                                             text='Create Frame with Entry',
                                             width=20,
                                             command=self.create_frame)

        self.get_value_button = tk.Button(self.master,
                                          text='Get value from frame',
                                          width=20,
                                          command=self.get_value)

        self.create_frame_button.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.get_value_button.place(x=10, y=40)

        root.mainloop()


class FrameClass:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, height=250, width=480, relief='solid', bd=4)
        self.entrybox = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=15, font='Calibri, 12')

        self.entrybox.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.frame.place(x=10, y=100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WindowClass()
```

please help, thank you all

Comment: Please follow spacing between equal signs and other measures to make your code more readable as specified by PEP8 (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Others may frown at you for not following this. It is a must-read for intermediate programmers.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, but PyCharm uses this type of syntax and I find it easy to read as well. Also PyCharm is probably one of my favorite IDE's other than Visual Studio for C variations.

Comment: that being said the link you provided is an excellent read, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

This is a topic I also used to struggle on. But luckily, I found a way to do this. First, make the `FrameClass` inherit the `WindowClass`. Next, in the `__init__` function of the `FrameClass`, initialize the `WindowClass`. Now, when you want to access an attribute of `FrameClass` in the `WindowClass` use `self`. This works because when you initialize the `WindowClass` in the `FrameClass`, the `FrameClass` passes its object (In the code below it is 'obj') into the `WindowClass` (`self` refers to the object through which the method was called). Next, if you want to access an attribute of the `WindowClass` in the `FrameClass`, you can either use `self` or `super`. `super` makes things faster but can only be used for methods and `self` searches in the MRO(First child class, then parent class) and can be used for attributes too. Here is your code to make things simpler to understand:

### Code

```py
import tkinter as tk

class WindowClass:
    def get_value(self):
        value = self.entrybox.get()
        print(value)
        "DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE VALUE HERE"

    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.master = root
        self.master.geometry('500x500')

        self.create_frame_button = tk.Button(self.master,
                                             text='Create Frame with Entry',
                                             width=20,
                                             command=lambda: self.create_frame(self.master))

        self.get_value_button = tk.Button(self.master,
                                          text='Get value from frame',
                                          width=20,
                                          command=self.get_value)

        self.create_frame_button.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.get_value_button.place(x=10, y=40)

        root.mainloop()

class FrameClass(WindowClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def create_frame(self, master):
        self.__master = master

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.__master, height=250, width=480, relief='solid', bd=4)
        self.entrybox = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=15, font='Calibri, 12')

        self.entrybox.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.frame.place(x=10, y=100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = FrameClass()
```

Note: It is usually recommended to create the GUI in another function not in `__init__`. I have removed the `create_frame` function and replaced it with a [lambda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/) function. I have also used [name mangling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/name-mangling-in-python/) to avoid confusion between the `self.master` of both the classes. I hope this helped you to solve your problem and increased your knowledge of OO Tkinter! Also, if you couldn't understand anything about the information given in the answer, you can comment and ask.

Comment: How interesting, thank you for your quick answer. Do you know any books or maybe internet resources about more advanced OOP and inheritances?

Comment: I also realized that by nesting classes this was 100% easier to achieve, but what a great lesson neverless.

Comment: Well, you have to go thru many so I recommend top sites such as geeksforgeeks, programiz and w3schools for more reading but I don't know any books (I don't even use them)